# Как изменить ссылки на объекты?

Tags: c++

В классе находятся 2 указателя на объекты этого класса, чтобы построить дерево, требуется, чтобы в некоторых случаях они были nullptr. Возможно ли в будущем изменить на какой-то объект, например при добавлении элемента в дерево? По-разному пробовал, все время ошибка, что невозможно менять l-value.

```
class Node
{
private:

    int key;
    int height;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;


public:
    
    Node()
    {
        this->key = 0;
        this->left = nullptr;
        this->right = nullptr;
        this->height = 0;
    }

    Node(int key)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->left = nullptr;
        this->right = nullptr;
        this->height = 1;
    }

    void insert(int k)
    {
        if (k < this->key)
        {
            if (this)
            {
                this->left->insert(k);
            }
            else
            {
                this->left = &Node(key);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this)
            {
                this->right->insert(k);
            }
            else
            {
                this->right = &Node(key);
            }
        }
        this->balance();
    }
};
```

Comment: *"все время ошибка, что невозможно менять l-value"* Пример кода с ошибкой давайте. `&Node(key)` Вот это не должно компилироваться. А даже если ваш компилятор это пропускает, то это будет делать не то что вам нужно. Наверное вы хотели написать `new Node(key)`.

Comment: Компилятор на другое ругается. Читайте внимательно. Что нельзя **брать** указатель у временного объекта.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я все ещё не могу присвоить this new Node(key), если я правильно вас понял

Comment: `left = new Node(key);`

Comment: Что значит "не могу присвоить"? Если я в вашем коде исправляю эти строчки, у меня все компилируется.

Comment: Спасибо всем, ваши ответы помогли!

Comment: Еще, `if (this)` - сомнительная проверка. В легальном коде this не может быть нулем, тем более что несколькими строчками выше вы его разыменовываете.